# what is equivalent to "in no city there is no guy with no car"?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

So this is a question From a Script. It didnt work out for me for more than 3 hours now. First i thought its the Option a) there is one guy in every City With a car but then i Decides that its more likely b) in every City there is a guy With no car. I really cant write it right With quantifiers and i would be more than happy if someone here could help me. Hopefully, reegards! Also if someone could send a link to similar questions i would be very happy!

Comment: "There is no guy without a car In any city * ..is that better?

Answer (score 1):

Start with "no guy with no car", that means "there does not exist a guy that has zero cars" and you can then cancel the two negatives (which I assume you already know how) to "all guys have at least one car" and you can keep going.

Answer (score 0):

"in no city, there is no guy with no car" = "in no city, every guy has a car" = "there is no city where every guy has a car" = "in every city there is at least one guy does not have a car".

Comment: I still tönt unterstand Show sou den weite this Witz quantifiers

Comment: Sorry autocorrect but i didnt unterstand where the no city went

Comment: I wanted to ask how to write this with quantifiers

Comment: @LaffaYett Are you  aware that "every" and "there is" are quantifiers? Mike has written the sentences with quantifiers. You probably meant that you want to change these English quantifiers to formal symbols like $\forall$ and $\exists$.

Comment: The Problem is i Understand logically that no guy With no gar means every guy has a car but i thought the negotiation of the "backwards"  E/ which stands for "no" is "some" so i didnt get to write it right

Answer (score 0):

$$\neg \exists x (City(x) \land \neg \exists y (Guy(y) \land In(y,x) \land \neg \exists z (Car(z) \land Has(y,z)))) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\forall x (City(x) \rightarrow \neg \neg \exists y (Guy(y) \land In(y,x) \land \neg \exists z (Car(z) \land Has(y,z)))) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\forall x (City(x) \rightarrow \exists y (Guy(y) \land In(y,x) \land \neg \exists z (Car(z) \land Has(y,z)))) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\forall x (City(x) \rightarrow \exists y (Guy(y) \land In(y,x) \land \forall z (Car(z) \rightarrow \neg Has(y,z))))$$

So:

In every city lives a guy that does not have a car